# Freehub Seal Orientation "Axis Sport Disc"

Tags: hub, freehub

I've serviced my freehub, and on putting it back together am unsure of the correct orientation of the seal between the hub body and the freehub.

I have a 2018 Specialized Diverge E5 Sport, with a 12x142mm thru-axle "Axis Sport Disc" wheel. I can't find any information regarding the specific hub used. It has "Axis" written on it, that's all. I've searched for information regarding what this hub might be but I couldn't find anything.

Can anyone tell from these photos which way around the seal should be?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There’s a visible lip near the outer edge in photo 2. Does this fit naturally in a part one way or another?

Comment: Actually yes you are correct! It fits perfectly into the hub side.

Comment: Well that’s good news, hopefully you’re back on the off-road. It’s ok, and encouraged, to answer your own question if you’ve solved it. Someone else might search the internet with the same problem and it could help them. Photos very useful

Comment: Since having a smart phone I've always taken photos of any disassembly process and labeled parts with a sharpie (when possible) for reference. Next time I'm just going to video the whole thing.

Comment: Question answered, and yes I'll be more prudent next time!

Answer (score 3):

Whilst I'm not 100% sure if it's correct, the visible lip on the outside edge in photo 2 fits neatly into the hub body, so I have assembled it this way. It appears to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was stuffed the seal into the hub body first and then inserted the freewheel body unit into the hub. The image you have on top shows the seal backwards. The sharp edge on the inner race of the seal faces the freewheel body. The flat side of the seal faces the wheel hub with the seal fitting inside of the hub body.